# How to use multiple programming languages together in the same program?

Tags: c++, object-oriented, python, scripting

Such a simple question, but I have not found a reasonable answer to this.

I currently program in Python, an interpreted language. I always hear of people using multiple languages in the same program? Then I hear them using scripting languages; Can someone on here please in plain english explain to me the difference between what I know as programming languages and scripts, and how on Earth do people use multiple languages together. That just does not make any sense.

How can someone use Javascript, PHP, and ASP together. Or program a game in C/C++ and use python as scripts? It just doesn't make sense to me, they are different languages for a reason, i assume, so how do they play a role with one another?

Comment: You answered yourself: "They are different languages for a reason". Some projects are big enough and have to tackle down many problems, each problem has a language where the solution comes easier/cleaner.

Comment: It's all bits at the bottom...

Comment: Just doesn't make sense. For instance I am busy programming a MUD style game in Python. Why would I use another language? What is the purpose of it? Preference? Bragging rights to say my program is written in 4 languages? Doesn't make sense. Even if you want too, how do you do it? Its not like I can write in Python code and say, "Here look at this C style code.. do your thing..." doesn't work that way.

Comment: @user3712563 - how many programming languages have you actually used at length? I would think it was obvious with use that they have different strengths.

Comment: I have used C++ and Python, a little bit of AutoLISP for my AutoCAD work. No I honestly can't find any strengths or weaknesses for either.. They all do the exact same job, one might be just more txt than the other.

Comment: LUA is often used as a scripting layer for C++ applications.

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as a "scripting language". Scripting is nothing but a mode of use of a language, and you can do scripting with pretty much any powerful enough language. 2) One must use dozens of different languages within a single project, it's the most efficient way of doing things. When it's not possible, then at least using two, three or more is always an option.

Comment: @SK-logic: be careful what you write - there will be always a guy here who takes you seriously :-))

Comment: @DocBrown, I'm totally serious. What made you think I'm joking? I do not know a single case where using domain specific languages won't provide a significant performance boost.

Comment: @SK-logic: actually, I expected such a kind of reply ;-).

Comment: This question is way too broad. At the very least, there are three questions here: what is a scripting language, how do you use multiple languages together, and why would you use multiple languages together. I'm pretty sure all three of those have already been answered here. So, this question is not only too broad, but also a triple duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

In many cases, when you see multiple languages used together, you will find that one is a compiled language and the other is a scripting language.

The compiled language is typically C/C++, but can be many other languages (Haskell, Erlang, Java, etc). The compiled language provides the base application. The base provides an interface to the underlying operating system as well as the foundation for the work to be done by the application. The application will often provide lower level functionality that makes it easier to develop using the scripting interface.

The scripting language is most often used to provide customization for the application. The customization can be part of the application provided by the vendor for their own convenience or the scripting interface can provide customization for the end user.

Many times, the script interface will provide almost a Domain Specific Language by providing useful functions and high level interface specific for the application, making it more easily customized.

A couple of well known examples. Emacs is written in C and customized using Emacs Lisp. TextMate is a compiled application customized using Ruby. Atom is a new text editor that is written in JavaScript to run on Node. Atom is more indirect. The application is (nearly?) all JavaScript while Node.js uses V8 which is written in C++. World of Warcraft has a scripting interface that uses Lua.

As a personal example, I worked on a brand-able installer where the base code was Objective-C/C++ in order to access UI elements on MacOS with customization using AppleScript. The AppleScript interface was used only by us in order to brand the application for each customer.

As others have said, use the right language for the right application.

Comment: Maybe I'm being too pedantic here, but instead of "scripting language" I'd write "interpreted language". Compiled languages are complied to a binary that is interpreted (either directly by the processor, as is usually the case for C and C++, or by a runtime, as usually happens with Java or C#). Interpreted languages are not complied, but are run by an interpreter that parses and runs the program without producing a binary form.

Comment: There is no such thing as a compiled language or an interpreted language. Compilation and interpretation are traits of the compiler or interpreter (duh!) not the language. Languages aren't compiled or interpreted. They just *are*. Every language can be implemented with a compiler and every language can be implemented with an interpreter. Most languages have both compiled and interpreted implementations. Most modern high-performance implementations are both interpreted and compiled. There are interpreters for C and C++, there are compilers for JavaScript and Lisp.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: you are correct, but do you really think this clarifies anything for the OP? I guess I will change the question title to reflect more what the OP really asks in the question body (which actually does not match the title).

Answer (score 3):

Bill Door gave some good examples where the "main program" is written in C or C++, and a scripting language is included for customization, But there is also a common, but different scenario, where the "main program", written in some "scripting language" (whatever people have in mind when they use that word) is extended by modules written in C or C++. For example, in Python, a typical use case would be to [implement an extension or module in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm), because of the better performance one can typically achieve this way. That's why the core parts of Python modules like NumPy or SciPy are mostly written in C, or PyGame, or the Python Imaging Library (PIL).

Comment: And it's actually the most common definition of what "scripting" is - a lightweight *glue* which binds together various smaller modules or standalone programs.

Answer (score 2):

**Interoperability is usually achieved by transferring data**

Generally, you can think each language being it's own separate program. This is not always the case though...

Some examples:

1. Sending sql queries to a database
2. using json_encode() in php to encode a data structure into it's string representation, which then can be decoded by java script.
3. Exposing an api which can be called by an embedded interpreter. This api can be exposed by memory addresses (think lua tied in with c++). Another example is Jython, python that can be ran on the JVM.

Some reasons you want to do this:

1. Some problems are easier to solve in other languages
2. You can extend a binary program without having to re-compile it
3. Tying in existing solutions so you don't have to write stuff from scratch.