# How are complex programs made?

Tags: php, javascript, programming-languages, python, c

I know a few languages, and can program in them. How do multiple languages blend together in a single program? For ex. https://github.com/facebook/watchman. This uses C, PHP, Python, Javascript, etc. How exactly do these languages combine to give a single result? How do they interact with each other? How do I learn to do this?

And I have seen this question but I don't think this is the same: [How to use multiple programming languages together in the same program?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267167/how-to-use-multiple-programming-languages-together-in-the-same-program) As my question is about the exact way these things interact and how to learn it whereas the above question is just about how they interact, which also has no detailed answers.

Comment: Why the C++ tag? Nothing in the question is specific to C++ ...

Comment: Because the facebook/watchman uses those languages, so I thought maybe its language specific.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but your question title does not match your question. "Complexity of a program" and "interaction of multiple languages" are very different things. And asking for "how do I learn this" is asking for educational advice, which is explicitly off-topic due to the site rules. In the current form, your question will probably be closed by the community either for beeing unclear, too broad, and/or beeing off-topic.

Comment: Okay, you're right. So, where should I ask "how do I learn this"? And the other question has no detailed answers whereas I need a detailed answer. In this case what do I do?

Comment: @user194207: you need to go to some University and study computer science for several years.

Comment: AFAIK we do not have a site in the SE network for educational advice, sorry. Google may be a start, the software engineering shelf of your local library maybe, too. Moreover, you should decide which of the two different questions you want to get answered, and tell us why the other answer is in your eyes "not detailed" enough - for me, it looks like a detailed answer (as detailed as you can expect it to be here on Programmers.)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that a complex program does not need to be coded in several languages. For example, the Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org) is a complex program (of more than ten millions source lines of C code with a bit of assembly). And the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler has more than ten millions lines of C++ code (it was C code before 4.5, and switched to C++ in [GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html)), some of them being generated by internal utilities.

Then, mixing multiple languages is implementation specific (often related to [foreign function interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface)) but most language implementations offer the ability to call foreign C code. The point is that a computer system has a convention called [application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI, such as the [x86-64 SVR4 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf)), and language implementations are generally following that ABI convention, notably for [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (perhaps with the help of [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/)).

And a software can be running on several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) which are somehow communicating using some [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC), e.g. for [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) (such as [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)). Details are [Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific. On Linux, read about [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) etc... so read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Some programs are running in a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) having several [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) (e.g. to run on several cores in parallel of a [multi-core processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor)).

[Distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) or [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) or [concurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing) computing is difficult. You'll need years of study and experience to understand and somehow master it.

A common way to combine partial results in a distributed computation is [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Answer (score 1):

You compile each source file into object files using the appropriate complier for its language, then link the object files into an executable, the same way you would for any other program.

For this to work, all the compilers have to agree on how the modules communicate with each other.  This includes things such as: what symbol names the objects export and import, what format the data is in, how arguments get passed to functions, who allocates and frees memory, when and how.  Sometimes, the languages normally do things differently, and you need a special keyword.  There used to be a lot of different variants, but modern ABIs tend to be designed to make this easier than it used to be.

A specific example: C++ and C are very similar languages, but in order for a C and a C++ program to call each other’s functions, the C++ program needs to declare them as `extern "C"`.  This is because C can only export one symbol named `foo`, but C++ lets you declare both `int foo(int)` and `int foo(double)` as different functions, so it needs to give them different names internally.  To communicate with modules in other languages, it has to turn that off. `extern "C"` tells the C++ compiler to use the same name a C compiler would for that function.  In Fortran, all function arguments can be modified, which means that to call f(x) in Fortran, a C program would need to call f(&x).  In C, a string is terminated by a null byte that you have to search for, but in many other languages, the first few bytes of each string are its length.  C lets functions, most famously `printf()`, take any number and type of arguments, and that doesn’t let it pass arguments in some of the ways that other languages have done it.

There are a lot of variants, but if your compilers can write code that talks to each other, there will be some convention both mutually know how to use.

Comment: An example of parameter passing convention that comes to my mind: C compilers often push the arguments to a function on the stack from right to left, whereas some Pascal compilers push them from left to right.

Comment: That’s a good example.  These days, they’d both pass the first several in registers, but let’s assume we’ve got to run on an 80386SX .  Everything goes on the stack.  You’re writing a Pascal compiler.  What order to you push arguments in?  It’s reasonable to say, the order they’re written.  Who cleans up the stack?  It saves a lot of bytes if you have the called function do that once, not every caller.  Now let’s look at `printf()` from the C stdlib.  The format string must be read first, so it must be pushed last.  Only the caller knows how many arguments it gave, so it has to clean up.

Comment: Also, back in the days of 16-bit Windows, the operating system used the Pascal calling convention, even though Delphi was as close as anyone got to Pascal on it, so all your C callbacks and syscalls had to be declared FAR PASCAL.  Now PASCAL is aliased to WINAPI.

Comment: One reason for the C convention was to allow a variable number of arguments in function calls, e.g. in the `printf` function. As far as I can remember, Pascal did not have this requirement.